# Not possible to unreserve more products than you have in stock - Odoo 14 stock forecasting/reserve issue

Tags: odoo, stock, odoo-14

**Odoo v14E**

While an order is open,delivery is waiting & some stocks are partially reserved.
Consider following

**Current stock:**

| Product | On Hand |
| --- | --- |
| A | 50 |
| B | 30 |

**DO(Awaiting):**

| Product | Demand | Reserved | To Do |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| B | 50 | 30 | 30 |

Now, 30 is reserved for B. **And you make stock adjustment of B from 30 to 15.**

After that when you try to validate delivery (with/without back order), you fill face this error:

**Not possible to unreserve more products(Product B) than you have in stock.**

Kindly let me know if anyone is able to resolve this. I could see an open issue still there related to this, but not a proper solution is available.

Related Issue: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/62139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved for [Odoo 14.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/79180) and [Odoo 13.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/81127) by adding server action to check all the quants and their relative move line if match correctly. If not it will remove the reservation from both. It could remove the reservation from some `pickings` and `stock.move`.

The server action called from `_update_reserved_quantity` method in `stock_quant.py`

You can check it and do the same in Odoo 12.0

Comment: Thanks for sharing.
This seems like a hack, would not call it a resolution. In big picture resetting reserved quantity creates confusion in delivery plans for companies handling complex daily stock moves.